# Handling exceptions in CXF JAX-RS client

Tags: exception, cxf, jax-rs

I want to convert HTTP status codes to Java Exceptions in my CXF rest client. According to the [official documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Handlingexceptions) I need to use ResponseExceptionMapper, but there is no example to make it work. My understanding is that I need to register it as a provider, but how can I do that with a proxy type of client? I tried the following code

```
//create a proxy client     
locationService = JAXRSClientFactory.create(applicationURI + "/rest/", LocationService.class);

//registering my ResponseExceptionMapper
ProviderFactory.getSharedInstance().registerUserProvider(LocationResponseExceptionMapper.getInstance());
```

but it is not working, because ProviderFactory.getSharedInstance() returns a different ProviderFactory instance then the instance used by my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply exception mapper to proxy factory using [this signature](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List%29):

```
//create a proxy client with specified exception mapping provider
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
providers.add(LocationResponseExceptionMapper.getInstance());
locationService = JAXRSClientFactory.create(applicationURI + "/rest/", LocationService.class, providers);
```